# Makefile No such file or directory error happened when the file included include other file

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, makefile, g++, gnu-make

I got some problems when I tried to build my c++ project with **Makefile**.Then I found what happened.
For example, there are three files: **main.cc** ,**bar1** , **bar2** ,**Makefile**

**main.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a/a/bar2"

using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<which()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**bar1**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

cout<<"bar1"<<endl;
```

**bar2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a/bar1"
using namespace std;
void which(){
     cout<<"bar2"<<endl;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
comeon:
    g++ -Ia -Ia/a main.C
```

and they were saved on the disk like :

```
<Myproject>
|-main.cc
|-Makefile
|-<a>
  |-bar1
  |-<a>
     |-bar2
```

When I tried to build project like:

```
I:\Myproject\>make
```

I got the error:

> g++ -Ia -Ia/a main.cc
>   In file included from main.cc:2:0:
>   a/a/bar2:2:18: fatal error: a/bar1: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [comeon] Error 1

I changed the

```
#include "a/a/bar2"
```

to

```
#include "a/bar1"
```

in main.cc file

add

```
#include "a/a/bar2"
```

in bar1 file

of course,delete

```
#include "a/bar1"
```

in bar2 file,and
execute command

```
make
```

Then I got the errors below:

> In file included from main.C:2:0:
>   a/bar1:2:20: fatal error: a/a/bar2: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [comeon] Error 1

Compare this error information with the another one mentioned earlier, I think the compiler actually could find both bar1 and bar2 file (errors happened when compile **bar1** or **bar2** file ),but the compiler somehow couldn't find the another include file when compile the file that included by **main.cc** .

So,how to solve the problem ? Thanks! ^-^

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the include in `bar2` is looking for `bar1` here:

```
<Myproject>
|-main.cc
|-Makefile
|-<a>
  |-bar1
  |-<a>
     |-bar2
     |-<a>
        |-bar1
```

if you change the `#include "a/bar1"` in `bar2` to `#include "../bar1"` it will instead look in the parent directory of `bar2`

Comment: Is there any way to solve this without modifying the source code itself ? I'm using library from the other people, so I don't want to change the files one by one in the risk to corrupt the lib source files.

Comment: @wangkaibule: You can create a directory structure like what you see in this answer; put `bar1` below `bar2`. There are other problems in this code, but you may have introduced them when you wrote this simplified example for us.

Comment: I'll try to alter the order of file compilation or find other problems in my code.